# Google Chrome -- Command-click to reveal file in Finder?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, after downloading a file, I used to be able to cmd-click the file to reveal it in the Finder.

That behaviour is gone in Chrome 69 (69.0.3497.100) -- cmd-clicking does the same thing as clicking, it opens the file.

**Is there any way to restore to command-click-to-reveal-file-on-disk behaviour in Google Chrome?**

Comment: I've missed the old behavior as well. +1